How is 以上に used in this sentence exactly?

今起こっている全て―行為以上に己の感覚すらも、神様のせいだという気持ちになった。

The character is undergoing a  ritual "行為" which causes him an intense amount of pain and other emotions.
What I don't get is what 以上に mean here? "Everything occurring now, even my emotions,  I feel like it's god's fault.

In English one would probably say something along the lines of "more than the 行為 warranted".
X以上に basically both sets "X" as the basis, the comparision point or standard, as well as cranks it up to "above that", "even more than that", etc

I think you can go with 'on top of' or 'additionally', with nuances of 'more than', or 'beyond'.
In other words, [the?] god is to blame not only for the ceremony, but also the senses and/or sensations.
